# Есть ли эталонная практика валидации форм?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Есть ли какая то эталонная практика валидации формы с используя `js\php\css` ?

Например, обязательно ли делать валидацию на клиентской стороне, и если да, то почему?
Ведь, на сколько я понимаю, по смыслу это абсолютно одинаковый код. Зачем тогда проверять данные на клиентской стороне, если мы в любом случае проверяем эти данные на сервере?
Да и количество кода увеличивается прилично. Например, есть у меня поле `name`, получается алгоритм проверки такой:
 1. Проверить в `JS` поле на заполненность и на соответствие регулярке.
 2. В случае ошибок - вывести сообщение с ошибками. Массив ошибок записан в `JS` скрипте.
 3. Если ошибок нет - отправляем запрос на сервер.
 4. Проверяем поле на заполненность и соответствие регулярке + делаем запрос к БД внутри `PHP` скрипта.
 5. Если есть ошибки - выводим сообщение.
 6. Если ошибок нет - отправляем данные в БД.
Получается много дублирующегося кода в JS и в PHP. Нет, не то что бы мне лень это написать. Просто вопрос в другом - это вообще нормально? Может быть этот алгоритм должен быть сокращен, или наоборот расширен? :)

Как лучше взаимодействовать с `css`  используя `PHP` или `JS` ?
Например есть у меня вот такой код в `html` `<div class="valid">some text</div>`
Как мне менять класс div'a? C помощью `php` таким образом:
`<div class="<?=$validationClass;?>"`
Или передавать  результат выполнения `php` скрипта в формате `json` и уже в `js` взаимодействовать с `css` классами и не засорять `html` лишними `php` переменными ?

В общем, хотелось бы объяснения как делают серьезные дядьки, или какой нибудь пример из разряда "best practice".

Comment: На клиентской стороне проверяю для удобства пользователя, например, ему надо ввести несколько цифр, но не меньше трех.

Comment: На клиентской — только для удобства. До отправки запроса серверу и получения ответа от php-скрипта может пройти много времени, а если пользователю подсвечивать ошибки прямо во время ввода — это очень удобно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверять **нужно** только на бэкэнде.
На фронте это для удобства конечного пользователя.

Хорошая система фильтрации достаточно невелика, чтобы задуматься только об одной реализации, а то "тяжко поддерживать".

Отправку и проверку на бэкэнде можно сделать через AJAX, получить JSON, поставить ответ в модель JS и реактивно показывать ошибки (если Vue, например, использовать).
Передавать HTML в JSON можно только для того, что прямо нужно выводить (код модального окна с результатом, например). В любом другом случае это плохой выбор для работы внутри системы, ведь для этого есть JSON.

Comment: Возникает еще один вопрос. Допустим , если я отслеживаю на каждом элементе формы событие `blur`, то как лучше поступить - написать проверку внутри `js` скрипта(например на соответствие регулярке и заполненность), а запрос к серверу отправить используя  AJAX, по клику на `submit`?  
Или не мудрить ничего в `JS` , и при каждом событии `blur` отправлять запрос к серверу и все возможные ошибки получать уже от сервера?  
С  одной стороны второй подход проще, но получается на сервер будет прилетать куча запросов.  
Вот какой из вариантов правильный?

Comment: Не нужно сервер постоянно дёргать; если ошибся легальный пользователь, то JS отлично ему поможет исправится, а если "ошибся" злобный хакер, то он вообще не использует JS, сразу отправляет валидный, но ядовитый запрос.

Comment: я правильно вас понял, что всё таки нужно писать одни и те же проверки и в теле `php` и в теле `js` скрипта? А на сервер отправлять только по `submit`?

Comment: Да. В JS ставить валидатор на `blur`; в PHP юзать что-то вроде `$id = $request->filter(['id' => 'uint']);`.